# While loop form in PHP

Tags: php

I want to develop while loop form in PHP. I am able to create different name in each row but don't know how to handle POST value in next page.

Below is my code:

```
<form action="sms.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table table-hover" style="border: groove;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Id</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Today's Attendance</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $c = 1;?>
        <?php 
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$user = new User($db);
$stmt = $user->present();
while($ro1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>

            <tr>
            <td><input name ="uname" id ="uname" style ="border:none;background: none;" value = "<?php echo $ro1['user_id'] ?>" readonly/></td>
                <td><?php echo $ro1['first_name'] ?> <?php echo $ro1['last_name'] ?></td>
                <td><input name = "list<?php echo $c++ ?>" id ="cont1" type="number" style ="border:none;background: none;" onBlur="checkAvailability1a()" value="<?php echo $ro1['parent_contact'] ?>"/></td>

                <td><input id="press1" name="press1" type="button" value="<?php echo $ro1[$_SESSION['dyy']] ?>"  onclick="return change(this);" onBlur="checkAvailability()" class="w3-button w3-teal"/></td>

            </tr>


<?php }  ?>

             </tbody>

    </table>
    <button  name="back"><a href = 'attendance.php'>< Back</a></button>
    <button type="submit" name="next">Next</a></button>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "handle". It seems to me that having a `while` loop that assigns different values to the same `input` name will not work. Please explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: Query I used i.e. Select All student who is present today. So in each row I retrieve single student information. What I want : I want to submit value in next page as form do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give your input name a  counter based on the loop. You can use array notation for your input name, for example:

```
<?php 
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$user = new User($db);
$stmt = $user->present();
while($ro1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><input name ="uname[]" id ="uname" style ="border:none;background: none;" value = "<?php echo $ro1['user_id'] ?>" readonly/></td>
        <td><?php echo $ro1['first_name'] ?> <?php echo $ro1['last_name'] ?></td>
        <td><input name = "list[]" id ="cont1" type="number" style ="border:none;background: none;" onBlur="checkAvailability1a()" value="<?php echo $ro1['parent_contact'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input id="press1" name="press1[]" type="button" value="<?php echo $ro1[$_SESSION['dyy']] ?>"  onclick="return change(this);" onBlur="checkAvailability()" class="w3-button w3-teal"/></td>
    </tr>
<?php }  ?>
```

Then in your next page (**sms.php**) you can get the request parameter with `$_POST['list']` (without the [] ). That parameter will be an array in php.